# How to get the difference of the max and min of the row and input as series for a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
I have following dataframe. Values are the rating by customer. 
Ind  Department  Value1  Value2  Value3  Value4  
 1   Electronics   5       4      3        2       
 2   Clothing      4       3      2        1
 3   Grocery       3       3      5        1
```

Here I would like to make column range that is the difference of the max and min value from the row. Expected is as below:

```
Ind  Department  Value1  Value2  Value3  Value4  range
 1   Electronics   5       4      3        2       3
 2   Clothing      4       3      2        1       3
 3   Grocery       3       3      5        1       3
```

Comment: Why is the last row `range` is 2?

Comment: @Chris that's mistake. i fixed it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df['range'] = df.max(axis=1) - df.min(axis=1)
```

If you want to specify column numbers to calculate the range:

```
df['range'] = df.iloc[:,col1index:col2index].max(axis=1) - df.iloc[:,col1index:col2index].min(axis=1)
```

Comment: nice to know that i can use max with axis.

Comment: glad to help. if this works for you, could you mark it solved?

Answer (score 0):

You can try `numpy` `ptp`

```
np.ptp(df.loc[:,'Value1':].values,axis=1)
array([3, 3, 4], dtype=int64)
df['range']=np.ptp(df.loc[:,'Value1':].values,axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Filter for only the `Values` column and compute the difference of the max and min per row :

```
boxes = df.filter(like="Value")

df["range"] = boxes.max(1) - boxes.min(1)
df

    Ind Department  Value1  Value2  Value3  Value4  range
0   1   Electronics    5       4       3       2    3
1   2   Clothing       4       3       2       1    3
2   3   Grocery        3       3       5       1    4
```

Same end result, but longer route, in my opinion - set the first two columns as index, get the difference of the max and min for each row, and reset the index :

```
(df
.set_index(["Ind", "Department"])
.assign(max_min=lambda x: x.max(1) - x.min(1))
.reset_index()
)
```